# How To Use NSNotificationCenter In Sierra

Tags: swift3, nsnotificationcenter

I'm currently learning Swift for macOS and need to use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationcenter). In the documentation, it is said that I can use the class:

[image: NSNotificationCenter documentation said that I can use it for macOS Sierra]

However, Xcode doesn't seems to recognize the class:

[image: Xcode doesn't recognize NSNotificationCenter]

Is there some steps that's missing? Because, I get the impression that Foundation classes don't require import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift 3 it has changed to NotificationCenter.

Edit: this is an [example](http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/notifications-and-userinfo-with-swift-3-0/) on how you can use it 
I have no idea why it doesn't appear on your Xcode it can be a bug.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! Apparently, it is already mentioned in the class header on that page.

Comment: the reason `NotificationCenter` doesn't shown on my Xcode is, I already typed `NS` in front of it.

Comment: Yes, i noticed it a bit too late, that's why i edited the answer, sorry.